# Is there any impact if we provide more @Input() properties to provide data to child component? If yes, then what should be the limit?

Tags: angular

I'm passing @Input() to a child component. I've almost more than 10 input properties. My functionality working well. Is there any impact on performance if I use more @Input()?

Comment: Have you considered keeping all the 10 input properties as a Model?and use that model as a single Input?

Comment: I used one input property as a ngModel in child component and rest input properties are to just pass the data from parent to child.

Comment: can you post your code here ?